# Ways to read one indexed line from a list of doubles on a .txt file with c++

Tags: c++, list, double, readfile, getline

I have been experimenting different ways to write and read double numbers from a list of files. I've discovered that for extremely big data c++ has dificulties doing that, but my files have maximum 1000000 numbers and I always know the size of the list (how many numbers in it). I want to access this list from a program as they were elements of an array in a fast way. Until now, I haven't got the improvement I would expect in time performance.

My last version is something like this, a function that reads some number from the file:

```
Doub tret_1(int i){ 
Doub d;
std::ifstream read("tret1.txt");
std:: string sLine;
int line_no = 0;


while (line_no != i+1 && getline(read, sLine)) {
++line_no;
}

std::string my_string = sLine; // string
std::istringstream iss(my_string);

if (line_no == i+1) {
iss >> d;
} else {
cout << "error" << '\n';
}
read.close();

return d;
}
```

The numbers on the file are something like this: 1.216176826351508e+01. It does the job, but if I have 6 functions like that, that are called 100000 times by other functions it ends up taking more time/power then I have access.
So, my question is, what are the best ways to do that? To read an indexed value from a list file (that does not have to be a .txt) of doubles.

Comment: Why not read in all the data into a `std::vector` and then pass the vector around?  Disks are slow so if you are treating the file as an array you'll spend a lot of time waiting for the drive.

Comment: If performance is such an issue shouldn't you store your doubles as binary? There would be no need for an index then, you could just jump to the correct offset.

Comment: Opening, closing, and reopening the file again is going to be slow. Do it once, read all data you need, and then don't touch the file again.

Comment: And please don't use type-aliases for primitive types, like `Doub` for `double`. That actually makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Ok, I have thought about that. But then, I have the problem of the passing the vector as function. What seems to be hard on c++. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I have to access thoses values a lot of times as arguments of other functions, if I can have they stored as a vector fixed structure it would be a nice solution.

Comment: If you want higher performance, read the file, verbatim, into a buffer then extract the data out of the buffer.

Comment: Any sugestion on the specifics of doing that? I have to pass the arrays to classes/structures to access them from the different functions before I go into the main part of the file. How can that be done efficiently?